# Limit swiftmailer emails per second in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I am setting up SES to work with SMTP2. One of the limitations of SES accounts (atleast by default) is a 5 email per second limit.

I want to setup a spooler, as described in [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html). I can use cron to trigger it every minute, which is fine for my purposes. My worry, though, is that a large number of emails will become queued in this spooler and my server will try to send them all at once.

The article lists a method for limiting the total emails sent each execution, as well as a wayt o limit the execution time. Neither fits my use case though: limiting emails sent per second.

Is there any way to limit the rate emails are sent from the spooler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, you can use the configuration antiflood with swiftmailer (cf. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#antiflood)

**Example**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
    antiflood:
        threshold:            1
        sleep:                1
```

This will send 1 email per second

Answer (score 4):

## Better Solution

Using the Throttler plugin is /fairly/ straightforward.

I'm going to use YML because that's more sane for me:

You have to define a set of custom services. There may be a /slightly/ better way to do this, but it should work.

First, define your throttler service:

```
services:
  my.throttler:
    class: Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin
    arguments: [300, 2]
```

Now define your own instance of the mailer:

```
services:
  my.mailer:
    class: Swift_Mailer
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.transport]
    calls:
      - [ registerPlugin, [ @my.throttler ] ]
```

That should set you up to use the service my.mailer to send throttled email at 5/second.

### Original Answer

You're going to have to extend the default queue handler to make it work on a more advanced resolution.

Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport is where you're going to want to begin to look.

The other option would be to build a command to run through a daemon service that ran the default spool with the arguments --time-limit=1 --message-limit=5. That would re-run every time it failed.

Extending the SpoolTransport is clearly the saner option, though second resolution is going to be more intensive to track in general.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the rate limiting has to be per minute, not per second, for swiftmailer. There also does not seem to be support for this swiftmailer plugin (throttle) in Symfony. I've opened an issue with SF asking them to add it.

Comment: Strange, I use the throttle plugin with Symfony 2 without problem.

Comment: `$this->mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(
            30, \Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE
        ));` 30 is the number of messages per minute. found [here] (http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#throttler-plugin). If you set it to 60 it will send 1 message by seconde...